# how add number to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add a number to an array .

code:

```
var year = mm[2].value+1;
```

but it results undefined.

can you guys how to do this?

Comment: try `var year = mm[2]+1`

Comment: What is in `mm[2]`?  If it's already a number, you don't need to do `.value`   `mm[2] + 1` will suffice

Comment: What exactly is `mm`? You cannot add a number to an array, only to an array element or append it to an array.

Comment: mm[2] is an array in which a number is stored  and I am trying to add a numeric value to it.

Comment: @user1887832 Is `mm[2]` an array as well or did you mean to say `mm is an array...`?

Comment: @Asad: yes mm[2] is an array.

Comment: @user1887832 Please post the structure of `mm`.

Comment: var dt = "12/02/2012"; var mm = de.split("/"); var year = mm[2]+1;

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string to an integer before you add to it:

```
var dt = "12/02/2012"; 
var mm = de.split("/"); 
var year = parseInt(mm[2])+1;
```

Comment: var dt = "12/02/2012"; var mm = de.split("/"); var year = mm[2]+1;

Comment: @user1887832 `mm[2]` is *not* an array. It is a string. I've updated my answer.